# There is no /opt/redash directory, so I can't not setup Google Authentication

Tags: installation

I set up re:dash by docker by following the document re:dash provided.
I can connect to it and logging with admin/admin,
but there is no /opt/redash directory.
Therefore, I can't not setup Google Authentication.
How can I handle this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better venue for such questions will be our (Redash's) [forum](https://discuss.redash.io), as I got to this question really by chance.

If you used the Docker image we create (`redash/redash`), then you should have `/opt/redash` directory. Although do note that:

1. It's in the Docker container.
2. Instead of changing the `.env` file which will be discarded when you relaunch your container, you should just pass environment variables to the container you're running.

Answer (score 1):

The directory does exist within the redash_redash_1 container

here is my session, you can see that I have entered the container, and I am in the right folder

```
root@server:~# docker ps
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
    621875f04364        redash/nginx:latest    "nginx -g 'daemon off"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 443/tcp        redash_redash-nginx_1
    1b9211fcadd9        redash/redash:latest   "supervisord -c /opt/"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, 9001/tcp   redash_redash_1
    81dd2400f5ff        redis:2.8              "docker-entrypoint.sh"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          6379/tcp                           redash_redis_1
    84b55a4bc4f5        postgres:9.3           "/docker-entrypoint.s"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours          5432/tcp                           redash_postgres_1
    root@server:~# docker exec -i -t redash_redash_1 /bin/bash
    root@1b9211fcadd9:/opt/redash/current# ls
    CONTRIBUTING.md  Makefile         README.md    bower.json           docker-compose-example.yml  manage.py     rd_ui             requirements_all_ds.txt     setup            tests
    Dockerfile       Procfile.dev     Vagrantfile  celerybeat-schedule  docs                        migrations    redash            requirements_dev.txt        supervisord.log  venv
    LICENSE          Procfile.heroku  bin          circle.yml           gulpfile.js                 package.json  requirements.txt  requirements_oracle_ds.txt  supervisord.pid
```